# How to import local module to cosmos sdk v0.50.x (go 1.21)

Tags: cosmos-sdk

I'm trying to import my local module to cosmos sdk v0.50.x but the sdk does not reconize it. I did successfully with the chain-minimal and tried the same way with cosmos sdk but nothing happened when I used go mod tidy. When I do make build, I have this error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzF4mtpAgtwn4n5DkQfRIFJqdmqHV6dk/view?usp=sharing
So how can I fix this?